# Definition: branch of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Just wanting to clear up the definition of a **branch** of a complex function.

Essentially, given a "multi-valued" function $f$, a branch is any (single-valued) function $F$ on a domain $D$ such that for every $z\in D$, the value of $F(z)$ is one of the values of $f(z)$.

**Question**.  In some sources there is also a requirement that $F$ be holomorphic on $D$.  In other sources there is only the weaker requirement that $F$ be continuous on $D$.

Is there any consensus on this?  And does it actually make any difference?  (For example, conceivably it can be shown that in this situation, if $F$ is continuous then it is holomorphic.)

Comment: Strictly speaking you should forget about multivalued functions. The idea is that $f(z)=z^{1/2}$ is analytic on $|z-1| < 1$ and for any curve $\gamma$ not passing through $0$ the analytic continuation of $f$ along $\gamma$ exists. Then $z=0$ is a branch point because for $\gamma(t) = e^{it},t \in [0,2\pi]$ then $f$ transforms into $-f$. Then "multivalued function" really means such a function together with all its possible analytic continuations. It doesn't mean a map associating several values to each complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on reun's answer: a typical situation is when you have a (holomorphic) covering map $f: U \to V$, where $U$ and $V$ are domains in the plane, and you want to talk about $f^{-1}$, usually normalized at at a basepoint by a condition $f^{-1}(z_0)=w_0$ (think $f=\exp$, $U=\mathbb C$, $V=\mathbb C^*$ and $f^{-1}=\mathrm{Log}$ such that $\mathrm{Log}(1)=0$).

Of course if $f$ is not injective you can't define properly $f^{-1}$ on all of $V$. You run into problems when you want to define $f^{-1}$ around holes in $V$ (in this example around $z=0$). Those problems arise because you typically define $f^{-1}$ by glueing local inverses of $f$ along a curve, which is fine locally, but depend in general of the homotopy class of the curve in $V$. Different curves will give you different preimages under $f$, which is why you get something "multivalued" when you try to define $f^{-1}$ over $V$.

Usually the point is that you can make $f^{-1}$ single-valued if you restrict to a simply connected domain $W \subset V$.

I think historically this picture came from complex analysis, and complex analysis is still maybe the situation in which these questions appear most frequently. However this is really mostly a topological issue, which is why it makes sense to introduce definitions and statements in a larger context.

It is certainly not the case that "continuous multivalued functions are holomorphic", but for instance in the setting I described, if $f$ is holomorphic then $f^{-1}$ (defined on some domain $W$ where it is single-valued) is also holomorphic.